# Angular animation and staggering display: none

Tags: angular, angular-animations

This code is currently working for me but I got to this solution from trial and error and playing with the `stagger()` method.

Is there a cleaner way to implement this?

Ideally I'd just use an `*ngIf` but the elements are image heavy and the opacity animation is choppy from loading the images each time the element is rendered.

Ultimately what I am trying to accomplish is:

```
display: none + opacity: 0 -> display block + opacity: 1;
```

However I know that `display` can't be animated. So I am trying to stagger it to change to `none` *after* the `opacity: 0`. And then trigger `display: block` *before* the opacity is animated to `opacity: 1`

```
trigger('fade', [
  state('hidden', style({ display: 'none', opacity: 0 })),
  state('shown', style({ display: 'block'})),
  transition('shown => hidden', [
    query(':self', [
      animate('250ms ease')
    ])
  ]),
  transition('hidden => shown', [
    query(':self', [
      animate('250ms ease'),
      stagger(250, [
        animate('250ms ease', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ])
  ])
])
```

I am calling it in the template with:

`[@fade]="displayState === 'shown' ? 'shown' : 'hidden'"`

Comment: Hi can you put your code on stackblitz so we can help you further.

Comment: Two questions: Going only for opacity is not the solution, because of performance? And did you try your solution with visibility and not display: none? According to https://csstriggers.com/ has the most impact to animate.

Comment: Only opacity causes it to still take up block spacing on the page and affect alignment of other elements.